# Definition.Entity property is null

Tags: c#, snmp, mib, sharp-snmp

Whenever I create a ReloadableObjectRegistry with path to directory containing compiled modules, Definitions in the tree have Entity property set to null. The reason why I need to access this property is to be able to read the syntax of a definition.

I suspect, the Entity property only gets set after parsing a MIB... Is this a correct assumption? How else can I find out definition's syntax? The Type property is always 'Unknown'.

Sample code:

```
private ReloadableObjectRegistry Objects;
Objects = new ReloadableObjectRegistry(@"some_path");
```

P.S. By the looks of it, parsed module (.module) does not have any information about MIB Types in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open source edition SharpSnmpLib.Mib was designed that way, where most of the classes are just placeholders.

If you do need to learn the syntax, you have to use SharpSnmpPro.Mib at http://sharpsnmp.com.

A sample project has been published on [GitHub](https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmppro-sample) to demonstrate usage of the new APIs.